# Merge 2 video use ffmpeg but i want

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg

I have two videos of different lengths Video one: 12 minutes Video two: 6 minutes I want to take audio of video one I want to take image of video two And put them together Output video length = 6 minutes. Use ffmpeg one command please help me - thanks ( watch image )____

[image]

Comment: Don't [crosspost](http://superuser.com/q/1186824/114058).

Comment: tks Mulvya
my first topi ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 12m.mp4 -i 6m.mp4 -vf setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.1 -af atempo=1.1 -map 1:v -map 0:a -shortest new.mp4
```

The `setpts` filter alters the video frame timestamps to 1/1.1 of their present value. FFmpeg will drop frames in the cadence needed to preserve source framerate.

The `atempo` filter speeds up the audio to 1.1 times the original speed.

`-map 1:v -map 0:a` tells ffmpeg to include the video stream from the 2nd input (6m.mp4) and the audio from the first input.

`-shortest` tells ffmpeg to conclude conversion when the shorter (of the audio and video) stream ends.

Comment: I just learned "ffmpeg"
can you explain
-c:v for what?
tks you
sorry my eng not good? i use google translate

Comment: `-c:v` is short for `-codec:v copy`. This ensures the video isn't recompressed.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Mulvya i want 2nd video speed =1.1? can u help me

Comment: @DimaSan Thank you. i see

Comment: Then the video will be shorter than 6 mins. Edited.